# jQuery toggle object's visibility from center of it

Tags: jquery

**Plot Explanation:**

- There are bunch of divs with different size and properties and they all have a `box` class.
- All of boxes are hidden with `display: none`.
- These boxes cannot have 'absolute' position.
- When page loads, these boxes will start to toggle one by one.
- jQuery's toggle effect starts from top left of elements.

**Question:**

I want the toggle effect to start from center of boxes (both height and width). I mean if the box size is 100px*100px, effect should start from 50px from top and 50px from left. How can I do that with jQuery?

Comment: "note: the less code, the better!"...not true for people trying to help! Please provide code!

Comment: @Dom I removed that silly line. I think question is simple and understandable, but if you insist I can provide codes.

Answer (score 2):

If understand well what you mean, this should do it.

Running example can be found [here](http://www.charlottecoleman.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/jquery-show-element-from-centre-demo.html).

First write your html:

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="link">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="boxOne">Click Me</a>
 </div>
 <div id="boxOneContent" class="box">
     <div class="content">
         <h1>Hello World</h1>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Ut ullamcorper consequat dui tempor euismod.</p>
         <p>Nam vel odio massa, sed lacinia sapien. Cras ac
         nisi.</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

The id of the link matches the first part of the id for the corresponding box. For the demo I’ve added in a container div so users can click anywhere on the page to make the box close. There is also a container for the content within the box to stop the content wrapping as the box expands.

*Now your CSS, which positions the box centrally over the link.  I’ve only put the key aspects of it here, check the demo for the full code:*

```
#link {
float: left;
border: 1px solid red;
text-align: center;

width: 40px;
height: 40px;
padding: 5px;

margin-left: 125px;
margin-top: 125px;
}

#boxOneContent
{
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;

padding: 20px;
width: 160px;
height: 160px;
position: absolute;

top: 150px;
left: 150px;

margin-left: -100px;
margin-top: -100px;

display: none;}
```

By defining the width, height, padding and margins for #link, the centre of this element is 150px from the top and 150px from the left. Here are the workings: 125+((40+(5*2))/2) = 150.

With padding included, the total width and height of #boxOneContent is 200px.  Therefore the margins set will move the div up and left by half the size of the box.
This is what makes the div ‘grow’ outwards when it appears as the div is expanding bottom right (as usual) but also moving top left to get to these margins.

*Finally here is the jQuery that pulls it all together:*

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    $('a').click(function(){

        if($('.box#'+$(this).attr('id')+'Content').hasClass('active') == true) {
            $('.box#'+$(this).attr('id')+'Content').removeClass('active').hide(200);
        } else {
             $('.box.active').removeClass('active').hide(200);
             $('.box#'+$(this).attr('id')+'Content').addClass('active').show(1000);
        }
     });

     $("body").click(function(){
          $(".box").removeClass("active").hide(200);
     });

     $("a").click(function(e){
          e.stopPropagation();
     });
 });
```

If the box corresponding with clicked link is visible (active), then its hidden. Otherwise, any visible boxes are hidden and the box that corresponds with clicked link is shown.
If user clicks anywhere on the page (apart from links), any open boxes are closed.
Happy coding!

[Reference](http://www.charlottecoleman.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/jquery-show-element-from-centre-demo.html)

Comment: The content for the answer should be included in the answer so that the answer will be useful regardless of whether or not the page is moved, removed, or if the person looking at the answer doesn't have access to your page due to network restrictions.

Comment: @AndersonSilva Your example is the exact thing that I'm looking for, but you have used `position: absolute` for your box. As I said in my question, I cannot use absolute position on my boxes, because of their positions in body and their own contents.